# Unwanted Datetime Format CHange in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I'm trying to get the datetime of an event from n SQL-server and use the date to look up data in another table.

When I select the datetime variable from the 1st table it shows as...

```
2017-01-01 20:41:23.000
```

Data is parsed into a temporary table declared via

```
CREATE TABLE #RunData1 
(
  [MyDateTime] Datetime, 
  [Tag] nvarchar(50), 
  [Hours] float, 
  [id] INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  [searched] bit
)
```

I store this value in a Datetime variable `@startPoint` (`DECLARE @startPoint dateTime`) and set it using `SELECT  @startPoint = MyDateTime FROM #RunData1 WHERE id = @currentid_inner`

But when I then try and print `@startpoint` it shows as `Jan  1 2017  8:41PM`?

I thought at first this just might be some formatting in the print command.  But when I try and subtract 10 seconds from this (`SET @startpoint =  DateAdd(SS,-10,@startPoint)`) and use it to find data after this new time.  I get data from after `2017-01-01 20:41:00.000` not `2017-01-01 20:41:13.000` (data sample time is 0.5 s)

Why is the date format changing from `2017-01-01 20:41:23.000` to `Jan  1 2017  8:41PM` causing me to lose seconds?

Comment: OK i feel silly.  I was using CAST to convert the date into a string to make a dynamic query in a loop.  This was converting the datetime to the above format.  I fixed it by changing the CAST to a convert and specifying the correct style.

Comment: that's what you get if you don't post all the scripts

Answer (score 0):

You are not losing seconds - this is just how the date is being **displayed**.

When it comes to displaying `datetime` values - let the **application** deal with that - not the database.